# Writing a custom bash-completion rule

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have directories full of files with the same prefix, which I want to be able to quickly open in vim. For example, I might have:

```
$ ls *
bar:
bar_10  bar_20  bar_30

foo:
foo_10  foo_20  foo_30
```

What I want is to be able to be in one of these directories and type:

```
$ vim <TAB>
```

and it autocomplete to:

```
$ vim bar_
```

To achieve this I am happy to have a file per directory called ".completion" which has "bar_" in it.

The issue I have is I would like the following behaviour:

```
  * "vim <TAB>"  -->  "vim bar_"           // no space
  * "vim bar_1"  -->  "vim bar_10 "        // space
```

Where | is the cursor, so if a file matches, add the space on the end. If we're matching the prefix, don't add a space.

The best I have so far is this behaviour minus the adding a space at the end. I've tried all sorts of things, all to no avail. The following is what I have:

```
_vim()
{
    local cur opts
    local -a toks

    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

    if [ -f .completion ]; then
        opts=`cat .completion`

        if [[ ${opts} = ${cur} ]]; then
            toks=( $(compgen -f ${cur} | sed -e 's/$/ /') )
        else
            if [[ -z ${cur} ]]; then
                toks=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
            else
                toks=( $(compgen -f ${cur} | sed -e 's/$/ /') )
            fi
        fi
    else
        toks=( $(compgen -f ${cur} | sed -e 's/$/ /') )
    fi

    COMPREPLY=( "${toks[@]}" )
}

complete -F _vim -o nospace vim
```

Any ideas on how I can get it to add the space after the file name completion, but not after the prefix completion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that the sed part doesn't seem to do anything, so I could've missed it out of this example. I assume that's due to bash's handling of space delimited arrays.

Comment: How does this differ from bash's default TAB-completion behavior?

Comment: Many of these prefixes will be l_xxxxxx, and in the same directory I have a folder called lib, and also files starting with other letters. If I just use the default behaviour, it won't get anywhere. 99.9% of the time I don't want to open these other files though, so being able to just press tab to get the relevant prefix for that directory would be very useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailing space that `sed` is adding is getting dropped. Try this:

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'    # this will allow filenames with spaces (but not filenames with newlines)
toks=( $(compgen -f -- "${cur}" ))    # the -- protects against filenames that start with a hyphen
toks=("${toks[@]/%/ }")    # add a trailing space to each element
IFS=$saveIFS
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to quite work. It seems to flatten toks to be a single element array.

Comment: @d.haresign: I edited my answer to fix a missing `)`. Once I did that, the array works fine for me.

Comment: You're quite right, it does work... but only with bash 4. In bash 3 it seems to flatten the array. I've upgraded to bash 4. Thanks.

Comment: @d.haresign: In Bash 3 (and 4) it works if you don't change `IFS` (but you don't get protection for filenames with spaces). **However** instead of having a separate step to add the space, let `compgen` do it for you: `saveIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'l toks=( $(compgen -S " " -f -- "${cur}")); IFS=$saveIFS`. That will work in Bash 3 or 4.

Comment: I just came back to say the very same thing :-)